# How to map a data to a segment if the data is not in a collection in Kony Studio?

Tags: json, temenos-quantum

I am using **Kony Studio 5.5** for cross platform development. I retrieve data by using a JSON service. I want to print my data in a segment, but I can't map some of it because it is not in a collection.

```
"chartStat": " CHART NOT PREPARED ",
"passengers": [{
    "trainBookingBerth": "RAC9  , 8,GN    ",
    "trainCurrentStatus": "   CNF  ",
    "trainPassenger": "Passenger 1"
}],
"trainBoard": "Kovilpatti",
"trainBoardCode": "CVP",
"trainDest": "Chennai Egmore",
```

In the above payload I can map `passengers` to the segment but I also want to map `trainBoard`, `trainBoardCode` and `trainDest` to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Kony service editor, parse the output according to your requirement. By parsing the result one can isolate  the required parameter -i.e.: Filter the result returned from service- that are only required at the client side and in a format that we can specify.

If you have three labels in the segment and you want to show the `passengers` details return by the service, please follow these steps:

1. Parse your JSON data, while mentioning the `id` in the service editor, please keep in mind to use the `id` of the children widgets of the segment as the `id` for output parameter.
2. After parsing the you must get a collection which is similar as following

```
    [
        { "labelOneId": "RAC1 , 8,GN ", "labelTwoId": " CNF 1", "labelThreeId": "Passenger 1" },
        { "labelOneId": "RAC2 , 8,GN ", "labelTwoId": " CNF 2", "labelThreeId": "Passenger 2" },
        { "labelOneId": "RAC3 , 8,GN ", "labelTwoId": " CNF 3", "labelThreeId": "Passenger 3" },
        { "labelOneId": "RAC3 , 8,GN ", "labelTwoId": " CNF 4", "labelThreeId": "Passenger 4" }
    ]
```

Where the `labelOneId`, `labelTwoId` and `labelThreeId` will be the ids used for children of the segment where the data need to be displayed.

3. After this use the set data method of the Kony.ui.segment widget to set the data.

**Note:** If you did not use the id of the children widget then you will have to format the data using a "for" loop iterator.

Extracting the value from the sample value provided in your question:

```
var jsonReturned={
    "chartStat": " CHART NOT PREPARED ",
    "passengers": [{
        "trainBookingBerth": "RAC9 , 8,GN ",
        "trainCurrentStatus": " CNF ",
        "trainPassenger": "Passenger 1"
    }],
    "trainBoard": "Kovilpatti",
    "trainBoardCode": "CVP",
    "trainDest": "Chennai Egmore"
};

var oneVal   = jsonReturned["passengers"]["0"]["trainBookingBerth"];
var twoVal   = jsonReturned["passengers"]["0"]["trainCurrentStatus"];
var threeVal = jsonReturned["passengers"]["0"]["trainPassenger"];
var fourVal  = jsonReturned["trainBoard"];
var fiveVal  = jsonReturned["trainDest"];

var dataForSegment =    [{
    "labelOneId": oneVal,
    "labelTwoId": twoVal,
    "labelThreeId": threeVal,
    "lableFourId": fourVal,
    "labelFiveId": fiveVal
}];
```

Try setting this in the as the `dataForSegment` as segment data. If you want to add any additional value you have to similarly extract the data from the JSON object and form a collection suitable for your  segment.

Comment: ya i can map this i asking how to map trainboard,trainboard,trainboardcode,traindest all r in segment.. sorry bro read the question fully i cant able to map single data to segment.. not a collection of data.. because in my case some data r in collection some are not in collection.. in collection we can map like u said..but other than collection how to mapp......

Comment: @prabhakaranB, you need to format the data.[{ "labelOneId": "RAC1 , 8,GN ", "labelTwoId": " CNF 1 ", "labelThreeId": "Passenger 1" ,lableFourId:"trainBoard 1",labelFiveId:"trainDest 1"}, { "labelOneId": "RAC2 , 8,GN ", "labelTwoId": " CNF 2", "labelThreeId": "Passenger 2" ,lableFourId:"trainBoard 2",labelFiveId:"trainDest 2"}]. As said in the note. Need to use "for" itretor or need to exstract the data and need to create a collection from the available json object. Have updated the same in the answer provided above,please check.

Comment: the above mentioned code is for client side logic. however this could be achieved at server side itself using proper xpaths.

Comment: alright i am also searching but not yet get a proper op

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a very long time ago, but for anyone wondering how to do this, you can use the `addDataAt` and `setDataAt` methods you can use to *respectively* **insert** *or* **replace** a single row of data at a specified position in a Segment.

From **Kony's Widget Programmer's Guide** [about the `addDataAt` method](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_widget_prog_guide/Default.htm#Segment_Methods.htm#addDataA):

> Allows you to add one row of data at a given index or within a section.

```
addDataAt(data, rowIndex, sectionIndex)
```

and [about the `setDataAt` method](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_widget_prog_guide/Default.htm#Segment_Methods.htm#setDataA):

> Allows you to set data or modify an existing data of a row or within a section.

```
setDataAt(data, rowIndex, sectionIndex)
```

I hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this structure to put data in Segment...

```
 var data=[
    [{lblHeading:"Section1"},[{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"}]],
        [{lblHeading:"Section2"},[{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"}]],
    [{lblHeading:"Section3"},[{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"}]],
    [{lblHeading:"Section34"},[{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"},{samplelabel:"1"}]]

  ];
    this.view.segmentList.setData(data);
```